# Combining Objects in Angular 5 based on Value

Tags: javascript, database, angular, object, nosql

Im Creating a scheduling app using a NoSQL database built with Angular 5.1

Here is my Sample Data

```
staff = [
        {
          name: 'John Stewart',
          updatedTimestamp: '1520221418024',
          office: 'A',
          scheduledDay: '03/25/2018',
          scheduledHours: [114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121]
        },
        {
          name: 'John Stewart',
          availableHours: [100, 101, 102, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 200, 201, 202, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 220, 221, 222, 223]
        },
        {
          name: 'John Stewart',
          updatedTimestamp: '1520221418026',
          office: 'A',
          scheduledDay: '03/26/2018',
          scheduledHours: [214, 215, 216, 217, 218]
        },
        {
          name: 'John Stewart',
          updatedTimestamp: '1520221418025',
          office: 'B',
          scheduledDay: '03/26/2018',
          scheduledHours: [220, 221, 222, 223]
        },
        {
          name: 'Hal Jordan',
          availableHours: [300, 301, 302, 203, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 200, 201, 202],
        },
        {
          name: 'Hal Jordan',
          updatedTimestamp: '1520221418025',
          office: 'B',
          scheduledDay: '03/26/2018',
          scheduledHours: [218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223]
        },
        {
          name: 'Guy Gardner',
          availableHours: [300, 301, 302, 203, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 200, 201, 202],
        },
        {
          name: 'Guy Gardner',
          updatedTimestamp: '1520221418025',
          office: 'CB',
          scheduledDay: '03/26/2018',
          scheduledHours: [220, 221, 222, 223]
        }
]
```

100 is Sunday Midnight
101 is Sunday 1 A.M
202 is Monday 2 A.M. and so on.

What is the best way to combine this data so each user has their set available hours, and set scheduled hours so I can compare them and only show who matches the available hours, but isn't scheduled for that time.

I've tried using Object.assign with a filter which works with other objects, but I can't get it to work with this data.

```
combineObjects(a, b) {

const result = this.staff[0].map(val => {
  return Object.assign({}, val, this.staff[1].filter(v => v.name === val.name)[0]);
});

this.allStaff.push(result);
};
```

My end goal is to dynamically display who is available based on the time selected by the Admin without repeating the same person. If John Stewart is working from 2pm to 9pm on monday in office A, I don't want him to be schedulable anywhere during that time period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. You just needed to use `.reduce()` instead of `.map()`:

```js
const staff = [
        {
          name: 'John Stewart',
          updatedTimestamp: '1520221418024',
          office: 'A',
          scheduledDay: '03/25/2018',
          scheduledHours: [114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121]
        },
        {
          name: 'John Stewart',
          availableHours: [100, 101, 102, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 200, 201, 202, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 220, 221, 222, 223]
        },
        {
          name: 'John Stewart',
          updatedTimestamp: '1520221418026',
          office: 'A',
          scheduledDay: '03/26/2018',
          scheduledHours: [214, 215, 216, 217, 218]
        },
        {
          name: 'John Stewart',
          updatedTimestamp: '1520221418025',
          office: 'B',
          scheduledDay: '03/26/2018',
          scheduledHours: [220, 221, 222, 223]
        },
        {
          name: 'Hal Jordan',
          availableHours: [300, 301, 302, 203, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 200, 201, 202],
        },
        {
          name: 'Hal Jordan',
          updatedTimestamp: '1520221418025',
          office: 'B',
          scheduledDay: '03/26/2018',
          scheduledHours: [218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223]
        },
        {
          name: 'Guy Gardner',
          availableHours: [300, 301, 302, 203, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 200, 201, 202],
        },
        {
          name: 'Guy Gardner',
          updatedTimestamp: '1520221418025',
          office: 'CB',
          scheduledDay: '03/26/2018',
          scheduledHours: [220, 221, 222, 223]
        }
];

function combineObjects(a, b) {
  return staff.reduce((currentArr, nextVal) => {
    return currentArr.filter((current) => current.name === nextVal.name).length === 0
      ? [].concat(currentArr, nextVal)
      : currentArr.map((current) => current.name === nextVal.name ? Object.assign({}, current, nextVal) : current);
  }, []);
}

console.log(combineObjects('', ''));
```